# PHP ODBC: String Data, Right Truncation from LIKE clause in prepared statement

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc

Consider the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (a VARCHAR(8), b VARCHAR(20))
```

Then consider the following prepared statement:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM foo WHERE a LIKE ?
```

Finally, consider the following PHP lines:

```
$stmt = odbc_prepare($dsn, $query); // Where $query is the above query
$filter = "%12345678%"; // Note: two wildcards and 8 real characters
odbc_execute($stmt, array($filter));
```

With PHP 5.3.13 on Windows x86 (as part of the WAMP package), and both the Microsoft SQL Server ODBC driver version 06.01.7601 and Microsoft SQL Server Native Client version 10.50.4000, the `odbc_execute` fails, generating a "String data, right truncation" error.

If, instead, I substitute the filter string directly into the query, like so:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM foo WHERE a LIKE '%12345678%'
```

of course it works just fine, since `LIKE` isn't ever supposed to lead to that error.

Is this something I'm getting wrong about prepared statements, or a bug in either PHP or the SQL Server driver?

Comment: I think you'll need single quotes around the `%123456..%`  so make the filter like `$filter = "'%12345678%'";`

Comment: Seems reasonable but doesn't work.  `odbc_execute` still returns `false`, but now both `odbc_error` (sqlstate) and `odbc_errormsg` are both empty. :-(

Answer (score 0):

The double quotes may be causing the issue.  Try this code:

```
$stmt = odbc_prepare($dsn, $query);
$filter = array();
$filter[] = "'%12345678%'";          // single quotes around the entire LIKE 
odbc_execute($stmt, $filter);
```

Comment: the 2nd single quote is misplaced above

Comment: I tried it. With the single-quotes added to the string, `odbc_execute` returns `false` and both `odbc_error` and `odbc_errormsg` are empty strings.

Comment: @Lotharyx Can you try my updated answer?  If it doesn't work, I will delete it.

Comment: That doesn't error, but also doesn't return any results.  It looks like you're making an array of arrays in your updated answer, which isn't correct for the call to `odbc_execute`.

Comment: @Lotharyx Sorry, try it again :-)

Comment: Already tried that variant.  Back to the previous result; `false` from `odbc_execute` and empty `odbc_error` and `odbc_errormsg`.